# Reproducir diferentes videos, según el que se selecciona, en un solo reproductor

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery

Pido disculpas, hace rato no formulo una pregunta, y no recuerdo como poner las etiquetas.
Explico: Tengo una web, en desarrollo aun, en la que tengo un solo reproductor de video, y abajo, tengo imágenes con la etiqueta  y las url que son traídas de MySQL. El tema es el siguiente, si pongo por ejemplo esto en el mismo index.php que esta el reproductor:

```
<?php 
  $variablename = 'video-648a0a8fa6b416.93293723.mp4';
  ?>
 <div class="card">
 <a href="Videos - Sermones/video-648a0a8fa6b416.93293723.mp4" title="<?php echo 
  $variablename; ?>">
 <img src="../Estilos/imagenes/reunion_J.jpg" alt="imagen" class="card-img-top">
 </a>
 </div>
```

**Esto es sin la BD**. Y al hacer clic en la imagen, me reproduce el video en el reproductor asignado.

Esto funciona gracias a JQuery. Codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
let video = $("#fm-video")[0];
let anchor = $("a");

$(document).on("change", ".file_multi_video", function(evt) {
let $source = $('#videos');
$source[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
$source.parent()[0].load();
});
anchor.on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
video.src = $(this).attr("href");
video.load();
video.play();
})
});
```

Ahora lo que realmente hago, y me gustaría hacer funcionar es lo siguiente. Tengo este form que envía la url y un titulo a la BD

```
<form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="my_video">
 <input type="text" name="titulo">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Y todo funciona perfecto.

Ahora lo llamo en un archivo llamado load.php en el cual también tiene un buscador, para poder traer mas fácil el video que se quiere reproducir.

```
 require 'db_conn.php';

$columns = ['videos_url', 'Titulo'];
$table = "videos";

$campo = isset($_POST['campo']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['campo']) : null;

$where = '';

if($campo != null) {
 $where = "WHERE (";

$cont = count($columns);
for ($i = 0; $i < $cont; $i++) {
    $where .= $columns[$i] . " LIKE '%". $campo ."%' OR ";
}
 $where = substr_replace($where, "", -3);
 $where .= ")";
}

$sql = "SELECT " . implode(", ", $columns) . "
FROM $table
$where
ORDER BY id DESC";
$resultado = $conn->query($sql);
$num_rows = $resultado->num_rows;

$html = '';

if($num_rows > 0){
 while ($video = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {

    $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td style="display: none">'.$video['Titulo'].'</td>';
    $html .= '<td>';
    $html .= '<div class="card contenedor_lista" style="width: 
         18rem;">';
    $html .= '<a href="Videos - Sermones/'.$video['videos_url'].'" 
    title="'.$video['Titulo'].'">Reproducir</a>';
    $html .= '<img src="../Estilos/imagenes/reunion_g.jpg" 
    class="card-img-top" alt="Videos">';
    $html .= '<p>'.$video['Titulo'].'</p>';          
    $html .= '<div class="card-body video_bucle">';
    $html .= '<p class="card-text"></p>';
    $html .= '</div>';
    $html .= '</div>';
    $html .= '</td>';
    $html .= '</tr>';
}
} else {
    $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td colspan="2">Sin resultados</td>';
    $html .= '</tr>';
}

echo json_encode($html, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Todo muy bonito, me trae lo que quiero, como lo quiero y ordenado. Pero al hacer clic en esas url, no me reproduce el video en el reproductor, sino que abre una pestaña nueva con el video. No entiendo porque no aplica el JQuery estando así o hay algo que me falte. Agradeceré cualquier ayuda.

**EDIT**

Agrego el código del reproductor:

```
<video class="fm-video video-js vjs-big-play- 
 centered" data-setup="{}" controls id="fm-video" 
 poster="../Estilos/Logos/Logo_MAXT.png">
  <source src="" id="videos" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Tienes HTML mal formado. Nunca cierras la etiqueta `<a>`, por lo que probablemente no tienes anchors (depende de qué logre construir el navegador al encontrar el error), que es a lo que tu javascript hace referencia. Mi sugerencia es que corrijas el HTML primero, quizás con eso el error ya no se de.

Comment: Ahora me dí cuenta también que tienes el `<div>` fuera del `<td>`. Diría que en tablas HTML todo contenido debe estar dentro de un `<tr><td>`. Mi sugerencia es que también cambies eso o al menos dejes claro que sabes lo que estás haciendo (un link a la documentación donde diga que eso es legal sería genial en ese caso).

Comment: no me di cuenta de que me faltaba cerrar las etiquetas esas, ya las cerre, pero igualmente me sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Aún no las veo cerradas en la pregunta... podrías también incluir el HTML del reproductor. Gracias.

Comment: Ahi agregue el edit. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

He preparado un [Ejemplo mínimo y completo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) dónde se puede ver que tu código funciona y con él se puede reproducir el video.

Esto sugiere que tu pregunta no incluye los elementos de tu página que puedan estar fallando y que logran que no se reproduzca el video. Lo que quiera que sea, no es ni el javascript ni la estructura básica de HTML que tu script en PHP *debe producir* para llegar al resultado.

Acá el ejemplo, que puedes probar aquí mismo en la respuesta:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let video = document.getElementById("fm-video");
  let anchor = $("a");

  anchor.on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    video.src = $(this).attr("href");
    video.load();
    video.play();
  })
});
```

```css
.fm-video {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video class="fm-video" data-setup="{}" controls id="fm-video">
  <source src="" id="videos" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<h2>Algunos videos de ejemplo</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://download.samplelib.com/mp4/sample-5s.mp4">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/suX2M.png">
      </a>
    </td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://download.samplelib.com/mp4/sample-10s.mp4">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7sq8.png">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://download.samplelib.com/mp4/sample-15s.mp4">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k4Hk.png">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Qué hacer, entonces.

Como te dije en comentarios, el HTML que publicaste de inicio estaba mal formado. Es probable que el resto del HTML que genera tu script tenga también errores. Te sugiero utilizar un validador para asegurarte que el HTML está bien formado, de otra manera tu página va a seguir presentando errores aparentemente sin sentido.

Una vez tienes HTML bien formado, el siguiente código debiera simplemente confirmar que se encuentra el reproductor e imprimir la URL de todos los videos listados:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let video = document.getElementById("fm-video");
  if ((video) && (video.tagName == "VIDEO")) {
    console.log("reproductor encontrado");
  } else {
    console.log("reproductor NO encontrado");
  }
  $("a").each(function() { 
    console.log($(this).attr("href"));
  });
});
```

```css
.fm-video {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video class="fm-video" data-setup="{}" controls id="fm-video">
  <source src="" id="videos" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<h2>Algunos videos de ejemplo</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://download.samplelib.com/mp4/sample-5s.mp4">5s</a>
    </td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://download.samplelib.com/mp4/sample-10s.mp4">10s</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://download.samplelib.com/mp4/sample-15s.mp4">15s</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Sugiero que uses este script (o uno similar) hasta lograr que te devuelva los valores esperados, y entonces empieces a tratar de reproducir el video.